# how to convert YII2 query "where" conditions from array to string

Tags: yii2

I have an array of conditions for `where()` method, that can be successfully added to query builders:

```
 $condition = [
     'AND',
     ['archived' => 0],
     ['broken' => 0],
     ['gender' => 1],
     [
         'OR',
         ['visible' => 1],
         ['status' => 1],
     ],
 ];
```

but in some place I need to convert this array to string

```
(`archived` = 0) AND (`broken`= 0) AND (`gender` = 1) AND (`visible` = 1 OR `status` = 1)
```

and then place it to `select()` method like raw SQL statement

```
SUM(IF((`archived` = 0) AND (`broken`= 0) AND (`gender` = 1) AND (`visible` = 1 OR `status` = 1)))
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be a string, can't you use a subquery?

Comment: how can I insert query object inside of `SUM(IF(...))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`buildCondition()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-querybuilder#buildCondition()-detail) **and** pass params to main query:

```
$sql = Yii::$app->db->queryBuilder->buildCondition($condition, $params);
$query
    ->select([
        'myField' => "SUM(IF($sql, 1, 0))"
    ])
    ->addParams($params);
```

Comment: If the query is related to some `ActiveRecord` model it might be better to use its `getDb()` method instead of `Yii::$app->db` to make sure same connection component is used.

Comment: by the way we cannot put creating a definite string into separate method. It should be used only at once in method where we get data